# Django, JSONField, Postgres, and F() object comparison

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am hoping to make a Django query by comparing two values within a JSONField class. I ran across Django F() Objects for references fields on the model, but it doesn't appear to work with JSONField as it tries to do a `JOIN` with the later section. So, for example:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(default=None)
```

Let's assume the data field looks something like this:

```
{  
   "value_1":20,
   "value_2":25
}
```

I was hoping to query it like such:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(data__value_2__gte=F('data__value_1'))
```

However, the error is something like this:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'value_1' into field. Join on 'data' not permitted.
```

Also have tried:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(data__value_2__gte=F('data')['value_1'])
```

But am given the error:

```
TypeError: 'F' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Also; Django 1.10, Python 2.7.11, PG Version:  9.4.9

Any idea how to filter based on a comparison of value_1 and value_2?

Comment: This is just a guess, but try `data__value_2__gte=F('data')['value_1']`.

Comment: Didn't work : TypeError: 'F' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Django 1.10, Python 2.7.11

Comment: and postgres version too, pls

Comment: Have you tried doing it using `annotate` instead?

Comment: updated with PG version: PG Version:  9.4.9

Comment: I'm not familiar with `annotate`, I will check it out and give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way it looks, it can be said that F expressions doesnt support json field lookup. As you can see below the sql query generated for below django query

```
print Event.objects.filter(data__value_1=F('data')).query
SELECT "test_event"."id", "test_event"."data" FROM "test_event" WHERE "test_event"."data" -> 'value_1' >= ("test_event"."data")
```

In order for this to work on postgres, the query should be below:

```
SELECT "test_event"."id", "test_event"."data" FROM "test_event" WHERE "test_event"."data" -> 'value_1' >= "test_event"."data" -> 'value_2'
```

Whatever you try with F expression, it doesn't generate the format `"test_mymodal"."data" -> 'value_2'` for the expression.

Comment: I ended up re-modeling my data structures so that I can use F objects. Regardless, this appears to be a correct explanation and workaround, though, I have not tested.

Comment: Did you try to CAST the JSON field? I successully managed to do my annotation and filter on it. It only required to CAST() try with something similar to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54805003/2848256